# What's the flag/thing on the first episode of Sonic the Hedgehog TV Series?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

I was watching the first episode of [Sonic the Hedgehog (TV series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonic_the_Hedgehog_(TV_series)) on netflix when suddenly something flashed on the screen. I was able to take a print of it:

[image]

Does anybody know what is that?

Comment: Looks like some kind of staging frame used in the production of the animation.  I don't know the technicalities, but I imagine it would be used to establish which set of cels should be put down next.  I'm a bit surprised they left it in the final video, even as a single frame, but I suppose 1993/94 predates digital editing?

Comment: Interesting. I guess they missed it then. It looked like some kind of flag to me, really creepy.